# Deleting data loaded in cache memory during a browsing session

Tags: json, google-chrome, grails, browser

I have a Grails application running with a very heavy back-end data.Every selection made in the view of the application loads a new JSON file.I am new to developing web applications and I assume that this JSON file which is getting loaded is being loaded into the browser's cache memory(It's just a guess and I could be wrong too.Do correct me in that case).

Why I came to this conclusion is because, after playing around with the application for some time and making different selections in the view, I observed that the browser crashes(In my case, it stops responding) after the cumulative size of the JSON files loaded into the cache memory(assuming it to be cache memory) exceeds 200MB.

If the location where the files are being loaded is actually the cache memory(or be it any other storage location),I would like to delete the files loaded previously once a new selection is made.

If this solution is not practical enough then, feel free to suggest any method that will solve my problem.
Any help or suggestion will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the browser's [sessionStorage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/API/DOM/Storage#sessionStorage) (only accessible within a session inside a tab) or [localStorage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/API/DOM/Storage#localStorage) (accessible across multiple sessions across multiple tabs) using JavaScript.

These can store string data in the form of key, value pairs. So you can fetch the JSON data from a file and convert it into a string using [JSON.stringify()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify) and get the data back from the browser's storage from string to JSON using [JSON.parse()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse).

Assuming you're using `sessionStorage`, you can check how many JSON strings you have stored using `sessionStorage.length`. You can set a limit in your code such that if your limit is reached, you can delete the oldest one using `sessionStorage.removeItem(key)`.

Comment: I will start reading about sessionStorage but I will like to make one thing sure first.Is it actually the browser's cache memory where the JSON files being shown in the image (http://www.pixentral.com/show.php?picture=1rbqwy37ToSWTT1jKRybUYXELcHtvm) are being loaded?